# Force Reponsive FileManager to Use thumbs_base_path

Tags: responsive-filemanager

Usually when Responsive FileManager is opened, the thumbnails it uses are retrieved from the `$thumbs_base_path` folder (configured in config.php). However, in some cases (usually for very small files) the images are taken directly from their original path. This poses some complications for my project. Is it possible to force it to always use $thumbs_base_path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it's controlled from `dialog.php` in the root folder of RFM. Here is the "offending" code:

```
if($img_width<122 && $img_height<91){
    $src_thumb=$current_path.$rfm_subfolder.$subdir.$file;
    $show_original=true;
}

if($img_width<45 && $img_height<38){
    $mini_src=$current_path.$rfm_subfolder.$subdir.$file;
    $show_original_mini=true;
}
```

Commenting this out completely resolves the problem, but of course it's also possible to play with the settings/directories.